# How to merge filters from one search model to one findModel from a controller in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

The question is confusing, but I'll explain.
I have this search query from `AsistenciaSearch.php`

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Asistencia::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->joinWith('rutAlumno0');
        $query->joinWith('idPlanificacion0');

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'idAsistencia' => $this->idAsistencia,
            //'idPlanificacion' => $this->idPlanificacion,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'asistencia', $this->asistencia])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rutAlumno', $this->rutAlumno])
            //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'idPlanificacion', $this->idPlanificacion])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alumno.nombreAlumno', $this->nombreAlumno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alumno.apellidoAlumno', $this->apellidoAlumno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alumno.cursoAlumno', $this->cursoAlumno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alumno.establecimientoAlumno', Yii::$app->user->identity->escuelaProfesor]);


        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

And this a controller function using the search query in `PlanificacionController.php`:

```
public function actionVerasistencia($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new AsistenciaSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('verasistencia', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id), //findModel from Planificacion 
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Both Asistencia and Planificacion are related by using a primary key in Planificacion named `idPlanificacion` and a foreign key from that model in Asistencia using the same name.
The question is, I need to make merge with another filter, where the $id from findModel($id) is like the $idPlanificacion from the search query, like this:

```
public function actionVerasistencia($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new AsistenciaSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('verasistencia', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->andFilterWhere('like',$id,$this->idPlanificacion),
        ]);
    }
```

But I got this error:

```
Getting unknown property: frontend\controllers\PlanificacionController::idPlanificacion
```

Any solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

$this inside the controller is related  to the controller itself 
but your are referring to idPlanificacion alias  you are referring to a model attribute

could be you want retrive  the value  by the model eg:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id)
```

so could be

```
public function actionVerasistencia($id)
  {
      $searchModel = new AsistenciaSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

      $model = $this->findModel($id);
      return $this->render('verasistencia', [
          'model' =>$model,
          'searchModel' => $searchModel,
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->andFilterWhere('like',$id,$model->idPlanificacion),
      ]);
  }
```